# Finding elements in an array that are different from the previous one

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a list of events that describe the internal state of a system. The system can be playing or buffering. The state only changes if the "data" part changes. Say I have these events:

```
events = [
{ timestamp: 1399621649624, data: "buffering" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621649912, data: "playing" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621655253, data: "buffering" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621655536, data: "playing" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621661537, data: "playing" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621662404, data: "buffering" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621662745, data: "playing" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621674306, data: "buffering" }, 
{ timestamp: 1399621674540, data: "playing" }, 
]
```

I would like to find the timestamps (begin and end) of each buffering period, i.e. given the above data, I need to find:

```
from 1399621649624 to 1399621649912
from 1399621655253 to 1399621655536
from 1399621662404 to 1399621662745
from 1399621674306 to 1399621674540
```

I have this code, which is working fine, but is there a more straightforward (rubyesque, even?) way to do this? I guess it boils down to starting with one type and finding elements that are different from the previous one (because there can be subsequent "playing" states).

```
state = nil
buffer_start_time = nil
buffer_end_time = nil

events.each do |event|
  if event[:data] == "buffering"
    if state == "playing" or state.nil? # if we didn't buffer already
        buffer_start_time = event[:timestamp]
    end
    state = "buffering"
    next
  end

  if state == "buffering" and event[:data] == "playing"
    state = "playing"
    buffer_end_time = event[:timestamp]
    puts "Buffering from #{buffer_start_time} to #{buffer_end_time}"
  end
end
```

Note that there can be `buffering - buffering - playing - playing` too, in which case I'm of course interested in the first "buffering" event and the first "playing" event. My code catches that with the test of whether the state is playing -- it only then updates the timestamp.

Comment: do you always have the pattern "buffering" - "playing" - "buffering" - "playing" or could you have "buffering" - "buffering" - "playing" - "buffering"?

Comment: There can be "buffering - buffering - playing - playing". The state only changes if there is a different state :)

Comment: [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) could be useful: `events.chunk { |event| event[:data] }` returns chunks of consecutive buffering/playing entries

Comment: @Stefan Good suggestion! That leaves me at `events.chunk { |e| e[:data] }.to_a.each_slice(2).to_a.map { |e| e[1][1][0][:timestamp] - e[0][1][0][:timestamp] }` -- think this can be improved?

Comment: what about `events.chunk { |e| e[:data] }.map(&:last).each_slice(2).map { |(a), (b)| b[:timestamp] - a[:timestamp] }`

Answer (score 3):

This should work in all cases described, although it is undefined what you want as output when the last event is a `buffering` event. Clearly it has no end time yet, thus we cannot output a `from X to Y` for it. However, the value of the last event (or the first `buffering` event in a sequence of `buffering` events) will be the result of the `.reduce` function so you can capture the value and if it is a buffering event, handle it as you wish.

Basically, this follows a simple approach:

1. Transition from `buffering` to `playing` => output `from X to Y`.
2. Update previous event to current event, unless both are `buffering` events. In that case keep the first `buffering` event since that was the starting point of the buffer time and we need that later.

---

```
events.reduce do |prev, cur|
  if prev[:data] == 'buffering' and cur[:data] == 'playing'
    puts 'from %d to %d' % [prev[:timestamp], cur[:timestamp]]
  end

  # With 2+ buffers in a row, keep the starting buffer, we need its timestamp as start
  (prev[:data] == 'buffering' and cur[:data] == 'buffering') ? prev : cur
end


# Output 
# from 1399621649624 to 1399621649912
# from 1399621655253 to 1399621655536
# from 1399621662404 to 1399621662745
# from 1399621674306 to 1399621674540
```

Answer (score 2):

```
events.chunk { |event| event[:data] }.each_cons(2).select do |(type, _), _|
  type == 'buffering'
end.each do |(_, (buffer, _)), (_, (other, _))|
  puts "Buffering from #{buffer[:timestamp]} to #{other[:timestamp]}"
end
```

What this code does:

1. [`chunk`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) groups the items by their `:data` sequentially, so you'll get something like:

   ```
   [["buffering", [{ timestamp: 1399621649624, data: "buffering" }]], 
    ["playing", [{ timestamp: 1399621649912, data: "playing" }]], 
    ["buffering", [{ timestamp: 1399621655253, data: "buffering" }]], 
    ["playing", [{ timestamp: 1399621655536, data: "playing" }, 
                 { timestamp: 1399621661537, data: "playing" }]], 
     ...
   ]
   ```
2. `each_cons(2)` takes every two elements in the resulting array
3. `select { |(type, _), _|` selects only the pairs where the first element is `'buffering'`
4. `each` takes the first buffering event and the first other event, and prints their time.

Comment: Uri, consider chunking on `event[:data] == 'buffering'`, followed by `each_slice(2)`. The latter will give you a 'buffering' and an array of 'finishing's that follow, so you can just take the first finishing in the array. I can't test this now, but I think it should work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - that is a very good suggestion, but for the fact that there is no guarantee that the first element will be `'buffering'`...

Comment: Good point, Uri (and no guarantee the last element will be 'finishing'), but that's easy to deal with. I posted a solution to explain. Notice your solution fails when `events` contains one element (easy fix). btw, I've noticed you've been a busy boy recently.  Don't you sleep?  Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this using [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk).

**Code**

```
def pair_em(events)
  return [] if events.empty?
  chunks = events.chunk { |e| e[:data] == 'b' }.to_a
  chunks.shift unless chunks.first.first # drop any leading f's
  return [] if chunks.empty?
  chunks.pop if chunks.last.first         # drop any trailing b's
  chunks.each_slice(2).map { |(_,b),(_,p)| [b.last[:ts],p.first[:ts]] }
end
```

**Examples**

```
events = [
  { ts:  0, data: "p" },
  { ts:  1, data: "p" },
  { ts:  2, data: "b" },
  { ts:  3, data: "b" },
  { ts:  4, data: "p" },
  { ts:  5, data: "b" },
  { ts:  6, data: "p" },
  { ts:  7, data: "p" },
  { ts:  8, data: "b" },
  { ts:  9, data: "p" },
  { ts: 10, data: "b" }
]

pair_em(events)                 #=> [[3, 4], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
pair_em([])                     #=> []
pair_em([{ ts: 3, data: "b" }]) #=> []
```

**Explanation**

Assume the array `events` is as above

```
chunks = events.chunk { |e| e[:data] == 'b' }.to_a
  #=> [[false, [{:ts=>0, :data=>"p"}, {:ts=>1, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true,  [{:ts=>2, :data=>"b"}, {:ts=>3, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>4, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true,  [{:ts=>5, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>6, :data=>"p"}, {:ts=>7, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true,  [{:ts=>8, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>9, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true, [{:ts=>10, :data=>"b"}]]]
```

Drop the first element of `chunks` if it corresponds to `p`'s:

```
chunks.shift unless chunks.first.first
  #=> [false, [{:ts=>0, :data=>"p"}, {:ts=>1, :data=>"p"}]]
chunks
  #=> [[true,  [{:ts=>2, :data=>"b"}, {:ts=>3, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>4, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true,  [{:ts=>5, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>6, :data=>"p"}, {:ts=>7, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true,  [{:ts=>8, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>9, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true, [{:ts=>10, :data=>"b"}]]]
```

`chunks` is not empty, so continue:

```
return [] if chunks.empty?
```

Drop the last element of `chunks` if it corresponds to `f`'s:

```
chunks.pop if chunks.last.first
  #=> [true, [{:ts=>10, :data=>"b"}]]
chunks
  #=> [[true,  [{:ts=>2, :data=>"b"}, {:ts=>3, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>4, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true,  [{:ts=>5, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>6, :data=>"p"}, {:ts=>7, :data=>"p"}]],
  #    [true,  [{:ts=>8, :data=>"b"}]],
  #    [false, [{:ts=>9, :data=>"p"}]]]

enum = chunks.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ... :each_slice(2)>
```

Convert `enum` to an array to see the values it will pass to its block:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[true,  [{:ts=>2, :data=>"b"}, {:ts=>3, :data=>"b"}]],
  #     [false, [{:ts=>4, :data=>"p"}]]],
  #    [[true,  [{:ts=>5, :data=>"b"}]],
  #     [false, [{:ts=>6, :data=>"p"}, {:ts=>7, :data=>"p"}]]],
  #    [[true, [{:ts=>8, :data=>"b"}]],
  #     [false, [{:ts=>9, :data=>"p"}]]]]
```

Map the elements of `enum` to their desired values:

```
enum.map { |(_,b),(_,p)| [b.last[:ts],p.first[:ts]] }
  #=> [[3, 4], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

The first value `enum` passes to its block,

```
[[true,  [{:ts=>2, :data=>"b"}, {:ts=>3, :data=>"b"}]],
 [false, [{:ts=>4, :data=>"p"}]]]
```

assigns the following values to the block variables:

```
_ => true (had a variable be used instead of the placeholder)
b => [{:ts=>2, :data=>"b"}, {:ts=>3, :data=>"b"}]
_ => false (had a variable be used instead of the placeholder)
f => [{:ts=>4, :data=>"p"}]
```

The first value `enum` passed to the block is therefore mapped to:

```
[b.last[:ts],p.first[:ts]] #=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: Interesting approach!